# Microsoft ebook format (lit) on Linux

Tags: linux, conversion, ebook

I'm looking for a program to open a Microsoft ebook file (.lit) on Linux. It's ok if the program just exports the contents to a .txt (formatted or not). The best solution would be a converter to some sane formats (.rtf, .pdf, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is in fact a program called [Convert LIT](http://www.convertlit.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Here are some [instructions](http://ubuntuliving.blogspot.com/2007/02/converting-lit-files-in-ubuntu.html). That only converts it to HTML though. If you want PDF, someone made a [script](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=5308124&postcount=40) for that. You'll need [html2ps](http://user.it.uu.se/~jan/html2ps.html) and [ps2pdf](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/doc/AFPL/6.50/Ps2pdf.htm).